# Hide the view in recyclerview's item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

i facing a problem in recyclerview's item.

My Adapter's code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Profile item = mListChatting.get(position);

        Log.d("TAG", "CEK : " + viewable);

        if(viewable==true){
    holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mDetailBookingan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            //assume that one way is show first as default
             holder.mViewOneWay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             holder.mViewRoundTrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             holder.mOneOway.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_just_left_white_focus);
             holder.mRoundTrip.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.state_pressed_booking_button_left);
             holder.mSendBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    viewable = true;
                    Log.d("TAG", "CEK 2 : " + viewable);
                }
            });
}
```

Like my code above, I want to hide `mFormBookingan` after `mSendBooking` has pressed. `mFormBookingan` never show anymore until user calls it again.

I have tried with a lot of ways but still can't find like what i need. After i press `mSendBooking` the form hide, but when i send new item to recyclerview, the from `mFormBookingan` that has been hide, appears again.

**My Question, how to hide `mFormBookingan` forever? Until user call it again.**

Thank in advance, i will appreciate anyone who help me for this one.

Comment: Is that mFormBooking  equal mFormBookingan? I can not find mFormBooking  .

Comment: sorrry, i mean, `mFormBookingan`. I edit my questions

Comment: You need a boolean inside your model class to keep track of button visibility, I have posted a solution. Check and let me know if it helps..

Answer (score 2):

I not sure what the clear situation you want.
But if you want to set View invisible you can try this code then check it.

You need to add ismFormBookingVisible in viewHolder class as a boolean attribute.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Profile item = mListChatting.get(position);

        Log.d("TAG", "CEK : " + viewable);

        if(holder.ismFormBookingVisible==true){
    holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mDetailBookingan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            //assume that one way is show first as default
             holder.mViewOneWay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             holder.mViewRoundTrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             holder.mOneOway.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_just_left_white_focus);
             holder.mRoundTrip.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.state_pressed_booking_button_left);
             holder.mSendBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.ismFormBookingVisible = false;
                    Log.d("TAG", "CEK 2 : " + viewable);
                }
```

Comment: I suggest that the view situation should depend on your data list.

Comment: Thanks fo your suggestion, i have solve my problem also using boolean condition. but a little bit different with your code. i give +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Create a boolean in your model class "Profile" to keep track of visibility of button : say boolean isBookingVisible;

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Profile item = mListChatting.get(position);

        if(!item.isBookingVisible){
    holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mDetailBookingan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            //assume that one way is show first as default
             holder.mViewOneWay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             holder.mViewRoundTrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             holder.mOneOway.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_just_left_white_focus);
             holder.mRoundTrip.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.state_pressed_booking_button_left);
             holder.mSendBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    item.isBookingVisible = false;
                    //Use notiyItemChanged(position); or notifyDataSetChanged(); here as per your selection criterion
                    Log.d("TAG", "CEK 2 : " + viewable);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: actually i have solved my problem using boolean condition too. I appreciate your help, i give you +1.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing the value of viewable.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but it's not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**onBindViewHolder** will be called when you notify your data set.

So you need to save the **viewable** in **mListChatting**. When you click the button, change the **viewable** in the **mListChatting**.

And then, change the code in onBindViewHolder

```
holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(item.getViewable() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

On refresh android will destroy the view and create new view with new adapter data. So you have to track the current state (visibility) of **mFormBookingan**. You can use a simple visibility list. When **mFormBookingan** state (visibility) change update it in visibility list so that whenever the list is refreshed, you can use it to check and set the last state (visibility) of your **mFormBookingan**. Here is an example

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> isVisible;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Boolean> isVisible){
    // initial state list of mFormBookingan for each row of list
    this.isVisible = isVisible;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (isVisible.get(position)) {
        holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.mSendBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.mFormBookingan.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isVisible.set(position, true);
            }else {
                holder.mFormBookingan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isVisible.set(position, false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

when you click **mSendBooking** the **mFormBookingan** visibility will change and it will remain same after sending new item to recyclerview.